# Python ArcGIS 10.1 Search Cursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, cursor

I have a file geodatabase with a polygon feature class named "AOI".  The "AOI" feature class currently holds two records.  I want to loop through each record and run a geoprocessing task, for example the ExtractByMask tool.  When I run my script it only runs against the first records and stops successfully.  Below is my code....

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(AOI, ("SHAPE@")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        Extract = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(costraster, row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you planning on doing anything with the output? You need to save your raster object if you plan on doing anything with it. See [the examples on the documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002n000000).

```
import os
import arcpy

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(AOI, ("SHAPE@")) as cursor:
    for index, row in enumerate(cursor):
        extract = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(costraster, row[0])
        out_raster_name = "extract{}".format(index + 1)
        out_raster = os.path.join(r'c:\output', out_raster_name)
        extract.save(out_raster)
        arcpy.management.MakeRasterLayer(out_raster, out_raster_name, None, AOI)
        extract = None
```

Comment: Yes I plan to run other processes.  This is the first step in a three part process I will then need to run a Cost Distance and a Cost Path.  These clipped rasters are first.

Comment: The key here was that you were trying to use the row for your mask, when you needed to use the shape (row[0]). More importantly, that means that your call to ExtractByMask was breaking, but you were not catching the error. I think this might be because of the ExtractByMask loop being inside of a `with` statement.

Comment: Is this the best method for looping over individual records and executing a geoprocessing service against a record?

Comment: Really depends on what you're trying to do. For the problem you've described, you could also create a selection on a feature layer each time, use that feature layer as your mask environment, and then each raster tool would respect that without having to make all these intermediate datasets.

Comment: I have three steps total that I need to do, Extract By Mask, Cost Distance, and Cost Path.  So far I have ran the Extract By Mask and Cost Distance tools successfully but I ran into an issue with the Cost Path tool.  It was saying it cannot read the backlink raster.  Could there be something wrong with the script when I performed the Cost Distance?